# Black screen and cursor in SDDM

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xorg, intel-graphics, sddm

I have just bought a new computer (with an Intel Core i9 10850K CPU, so a Intel UHD Graphics 630 CPGPU).

It is shown here:

```
$ lspci -v
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9bc5 (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        DeviceName: Onboard - Video
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 144
        Memory at 6000000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

I am trying to setup an ArchLinux on it, but when it comes to starting SDDM, I get a black screen with a cursor at startup.

I have followed the [Xorg wikipage](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg) by installing `xorg-server` and `xf86-video-intel`.
Additionally, as specified in the [Intel graphics wikipage](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Xorg_configuration), I have created `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Intel Graphics"
  Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

After digging into my logs I get the following ones:

```
$ systemctl status sddm
● sddm.service - Simple Desktop Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sddm.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-10-09 21:25:16 CEST; 2h 11min ago
       Docs: man:sddm(1)
             man:sddm.conf(5)
   Main PID: 539 (sddm)
      Tasks: 16 (limit: 76963)
     Memory: 62.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/sddm.service
             ├─539 /usr/bin/sddm
             └─547 /usr/lib/Xorg -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{1d4eff37-b951-4f1a-aaed-3371dfcdcb66} -background none -noreset -displayfd 17 -seat seat0 vt1

Oct 09 21:25:18 barracuda sddm-helper[569]: [PAM] Starting...
Oct 09 21:25:18 barracuda sddm-helper[569]: [PAM] Authenticating...
Oct 09 21:25:18 barracuda sddm-helper[569]: pam_faillock(sddm-autologin:auth): User unknown
Oct 09 21:25:18 barracuda sddm-helper[569]: pam_kwallet5(sddm-autologin:auth): (null): pam_sm_authenticate
Oct 09 21:25:18 barracuda sddm-helper[569]: pam_kwallet5(sddm-autologin:auth): pam_kwallet5: Couldn't get user info (passwd) info
Oct 09 21:25:20 barracuda sddm-helper[569]: [PAM] authenticate: Authentication failure
Oct 09 21:25:20 barracuda sddm-helper[569]: [PAM] returning.
Oct 09 21:25:20 barracuda sddm[539]: Authentication error: "Authentication failure"
Oct 09 21:25:20 barracuda sddm-helper[569]: [PAM] Ended.
Oct 09 21:25:20 barracuda sddm[539]: Auth: sddm-helper exited with 1
```

I have also tried a `sddm-greeter`:

```
[23:38:20.242] (II) GREETER: High-DPI autoscaling not Enabled
[23:38:20.244] (WW) GREETER: could not connect to display 
[23:38:20.244] (II) GREETER: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
[23:38:20.244] (EE) GREETER: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: wayland-org.kde.kwin.qpa, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
```

While my `Xorg.0.log` gives me a classical:

```
(EE) Failed to open authorization file "/var/run/sddm/{1d4eff37-b951-4f1a-aaed-3371dfcdcb66}": No such file or directory
```

Which usually indicates that my video driver is not correctly configured, while I am able to perform a `startx`.

Here are the relevant installed packages:

```
local/libdrm 2.4.102-1
local/linux 5.8.14.arch1-1
local/sddm 0.18.1-3
local/sddm-kcm 5.19.5-1 (plasma)
local/xf86-video-intel 1:2.99.917+908+g7181c5a4-1 (xorg-drivers)
local/xorg-server 1.20.9-2 (xorg)
```

Is there anything I have neglected?
Thanks by advance.

Comment: Did you follow the Archwiki? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SDDM#Blank_screen_with_cursor,_but_no_greeter_shows

You may also try installing `xorg-xinit`, `xterm` and see if the problem persists...

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried, no improvement. `xorg-xinit` and `xterm` were already installed.

Comment: You see `pam_faillock(sddm-autologin:auth): User unknown`, how about checking `/usr/lib/sddm/sddm.conf.d/default.conf`? If there's an invalid user, remove that.

Comment: You are my hero! I actually put an upper case in my `/etc/sddm.conf` in the autologin part.

Comment: Yeah I guessed that!